# Estrutura de Dados, Fila Circular. Dúvidas sobre os métodos Desenfileirar e Enfileirar

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, fila

Não estou conseguindo entender os dois blocos `else` nos métodos `Desenfileirar` e `Enfileirar`. Mais especificamente as linhas:

```
this.tras = (++this.tras % this.info.length);

this.frente = (++this.frente % this.info.length);
```

Por que o uso do operador `%`? Não bastaria apenas acrescentar `+1` ao `this.frente` ou `this.tras`?

```
public class FilaCircular {

        private Item[] info;
        private int frente;
        private int tras;
        private int tamanho;

        public FilaCircular(int qte) {
            this.frente = 0;
            this.tras = 0;
            this.tamanho = 0;
            this.info = new Item[qte];
        }

        public Item getInfo() {
            return this.info[this.frente]; //sempre aponta para frente
        }

        public int getFrente() {
            return this.frente;
        }

        public int getTras() {
            return this.tras;
        }

        public int getTamanho() {
            return this.tamanho;
        }

        public boolean eVazia() {
            return this.tamanho == 0;
        }

        public boolean eCheia() {
            return (this.tamanho == this.info.length);
        }

        public boolean enfileirar(Item elem) {
            if(this.eCheia())
                return false;
            else {
                this.info[this.tras] = elem;
                this.tras = (++this.tras % this.info.length);
                this.tamanho++;
                return true;
            }
        }

        public Item desenfileirar() {
            Item no;
            if(this.eVazia()) 
                return null;
            else {
                no = this.info[this.frente];
                this.frente = (++this.frente % this.info.length);
                this.tamanho--;
                return no;
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            String msg = "";
            int aux = this.frente;
            for(int i=1; i <= this.tamanho; i++) {
                msg += this.info[aux].getChave()+" ";
                aux = (++aux % this.info.length);
            }
            return msg;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você apenas somar 1, o valor da variável vai crescer indefinidamente.

Ao usar `%`, você está limitando o tamanho máximo que a variável pode ter. Este operador retorna o resto da divisão, e é muito usado para casos assim.

No caso, o código garante que `this.frente` e `this.tras` não fiquem maiores do que o tamanho do array de itens (`this.info`).

Exemplo: se `this.info` tiver 4 elementos, então `this.info.length` será 4.

Quando `this.frente` for 3, a expressão:

```
this.frente = (++this.frente % this.info.length);
```

Vai somar 1 (`++`) a `this.frente`, que agora passa a valer 4, e depois pega o resto da divisão por `this.info.length` (ou seja, o resto da divisão de 4 por 4, que é zero).

Se não tivesse o `%` e você só somasse 1, `this.frente` teria o valor 4 (e depois 5, e 6...)

Usando `%`, você garante que o valor sempre vai ser entre zero e 3. Isto é feito porque arrays são indexados em zero (a primeira posição é zero, a segunda é 1, e assim por diante), e se `this.frente` fosse 4, você tentaria acessar uma posição inválida do array (já que o tamanho dele é 4, então as posições válidas são de 0 a 3).

---

Eu particularmente não gosto de usar `++` junto com outras expressões, pois pode ficar meio confuso de entender. Eu prefiro fazer de forma mais explícita, como por exemplo:

```
this.frente = (this.frente + 1) % this.info.length;
```

Comment: Atenção que o `+1` tem que estar dentro do `%` para não sair fora dos tamanhos validos, assim `(this.frente + 1) % this.info.length;`

Comment: @Isac É mesmo, falta de atenção minha. Já corrigi, obrigado!